# How to hide passwords in pom.xml file

Tags: encryption, pom.xml

So I have some passwords stored in POM file under profiles and I want them to be hidden or encrypted. Is there any way I can do this without maven encryption.

Comment: Perhaps they can be moved to Maven‘s settings.xml. Can you edit your question to be more specific about what kind of passwords you are referring to?

Comment: If it's over server credentials, then maven encryption is a way to go. Maybe you could edit your question and explain the use case more clearly. You may still 1. place the values into the env variables and refer the env variable in the profile/build 2. use encrypted values and let the application deal with it / decrypt. 3. Have a look at the jasyp maven plugin